Power BI App Change Re Circular Dependency?
My machine just updated to version 2.127.1235.0 64-bit (March 2024).  Upon opening unmodified, previously-published pbix files in the Desktop app (BEFORE a data refresh), I receive an error message stating:
"Unable to execute DAX: A circular dependency was detected..."
My file has been structurally the same for almost 5 years.  As neither the data nor the DAX has changed, it seems to result from a change in the application itself.  I can't find a related setting that would trigger this.
Has anyone else seen this and found a workaround?
